# Spring boot connection timed out

Tags: java, spring-boot, wait, sleep

I do a wait for 5 seconds in a spring boot method and i'm getting a connection timed out exception.

```
   @PostMapping(value="/api/stt", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   public ResponseEntity endPoint(@RequestBody String payload) throws Exception {
   ...
   int delay = 5000; 
   long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
   while(start >= System.currentTimeMillis() - delay);
   ...
   }
```

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
   at net.schmizz.sshj.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:126) ~[sshj-0.27.0.jar:0.27.0]`
```

I already tried wait and Thread.sleep as well as TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5); and when i do a post with postman i get "Error: socket hang up" without any exception in Intellij.

Any help would be appreciated
[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77WzB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that i created a file in target directory using file.createNewFile() and intellij auto reload restarts the application because of the new file in the classpath which cuts the connection when there's enough time which is provided by the Thread.sleep(5000).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is never a good idea to implement a manual wait in a REST API. If it's a resource you're waiting for you should poll instead.

But anyways, `System.currentTimeMillis()` will return quite a large number.
Example: 1426349294842

The request is timing out as the `while` is being iterated over 200 million times given the above logic.

If you really require a wait use `TaskScheduler`

```
taskScheduler.schedule(
    () -> {
      // logic to implement after time elapses
    }, 
    new Date(OffsetDateTime.now().plusSeconds(5).toInstant().toEpochMilli())
);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Is'nt there a way to configure the timeout in spring boot so that Thread.sleep(5000) works ?

Comment: Thread.sleep should work. The error in the original question looks more an issue on the Postman side rather than your application.
Update the question with a screenshot to your postman request

Comment: I believe its an issue on application side the thread is interrupted after the Thread.sleep(5000) because the breakpoints after it are never reached. I added the requested screenshot. Thanks again i tried upvoting your answer but i dont have enough "reputation" yet

Comment: Try selecting JSON rather than Text in that dropdown in postman

Comment: Did it, still "Could not get response"